# What to do if the Sublist isn't full

Tags: java, android, if-statement, sublist

So I am making a sublist that has x keypoints (variable), and it saved the best 300 in this `Sublist` List. Sometimes however there are less than 300 points found, and the List gives a NullPointException.

I want to just show a message if there are less than 300 points, but putting it in an `if` statement (as I did below) does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
        List<KeyPoint> Sublist = new ArrayList<KeyPoint>(pointToList.subList(0, 300));
        if(List<KeyPoint> Sublist != 300)
         {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The list isn't big enough", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
```

Comment: Define "does not work". Also, you should replace `getApplicationContext()` with `YourActivity.this` if you are inside of an `Activity` method

Comment: putting the `List<KeyPoint> Sublist != 300` in the `if-statement` is not allowed, but Eclipse has "no suggestions" for it, except that it is wrong

Comment: Try if `(Sublist.size() < 300)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `if(List<KeyPoint> Sublist != 300)` cannot work because it cannot be compiled because it is syntactically wrong.

I believe that you wanted to say:

`if(Sublist.size() != 300) {...}`

The second point is that java programmers start variables and methods identifier with small letter. Please follow naming conventions that 99.9999% people use and this number will reach 100%.

Then, your check does not have any sense to prevent `NullPointerException`. The statement `list.subList()` may throw this exception if `list` is `null`. It can throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if parameters exceed the original list size.

So, something is wrong here. If you want us to help you please try to post correct code and exception stack trace. Stack trace contains lines numbers but since we do not have full code of your class we cannot know where exactly the exception is thrown. So, to increase a chance that people will help you please mark the point where exception was thrown using clear comment.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a : pointToList.subList(0, 300)
If there are no 300 elements in the List it is normal that you get a NPE. What you could do is first get the size of the list and then make a sublist of it.

I dont know if this helps you?

Comment: I only get less than 300 elements if the image for example is black (no keypoints are found)You mean that I should check if the list is less than 300, that the sublist should not be made? I could indeed try that